# Error Thread ! : Breakpoint1.1と表示される原因について

Tags: swift

現在市販のアプリ教本を買って勉強しています。
信号に見立てたボタンを配置し、ボタンを押すことでラベルの文字が変わるという動きを
作ろうとしているのですが、青、黄色のボタンはうまくできシミュレータでも動作が確認できたのに対し、赤のボタンはシミュレータでボタンを押すとシミュレータは落ちてしまい、

```
Error Thread ! : Breakpoint1.1
```

が表示されます。
Threadについてはよくわからなくてアシスタントエディタで接続を間違えたのかと思い、接続を切ってみたのですがよくわからなくなってしまいました。何か解決策があれば教えてください。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func blueBtnPushed(sender: AnyObject) {
        resultLabel.text = "しんごうはあおいろ!"
        resultLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }

    @IBAction func yellowBtnPushed(sender: AnyObject) {
        resultLabel.text = "しんごうはきいろ!"
        resultLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }

    @IBAction func redBtnPushed(sender: AnyObject) {
       resultLabel.text = "しんごうはあかいろ！"
       resultLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: breakpointが意図しないところで張られていたりしませんでしょうか？同様の問題で躓いている人がいるので、次のページ等が参考になるかもしれません。(シミュレータが落ちてしまうとのことなので、別の問題の可能性もありますが…。)
参考URL1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821587/ios-app-breakpoints-on-running
参考URL2: http://blog.praisefirst.jp/2014/06/swifttwitter_10.html

Comment: 接続を切ったとあったので、もしかしてですが。StoryBoard上のボタンの上で２本指タップしてみてください。接続が完全に切られていないかもしれないです。
上記のソースコードを入力したところ実行できましたよ

Comment: sugawaraさんありがとうございました。接続は完全に切られてはいませんでした。ご迷惑おかけしました。
Takahiroさんありがとうございました。リンク先の情報を参考にし、breakpointを削除してみたところ正常に動くようになりました。
お二方ともお世話になりました。

Answer (score 1):

コメントより

> sugawaraさんありがとうございました。接続は完全に切られてはいませんでした。ご迷惑おかけしました。 Takahiroさんありがとうございました。リンク先の情報を参考にし、breakpointを削除してみたところ正常に動く‌​ようになりました。 お二方ともお世話になりました。 – kobocchan

breakpointが意図しないところに貼られていたようです